# Changing template when applying cell style in xls file using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a problem with `HSSFWorkbook` object. I have a XLS template, where row no 14 is light gray, and next rows are populated with bean values.

During generation of the report, I want to change the date style for which I am writing below code but it's changing the whole tempalate.

```
workbook = (HSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(finalFilePath));

sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
workbook.setActiveSheet(0);

CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

HSSFCellStyle importDataDateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
importDataDateStyle.setDataFormat(creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("M/d/yyyy"));

BeanClass bean = new BeanClass();
if (bean.getLastDate() != null) {
    migrationBeanRow.createCell(6).setCellValue(lastDate);

} else {
    migrationBeanRow.createCell(6).setCellValue(notAvailable);
}
migrationBeanRow.getCell(6).setCellStyle(cellStyleDate);

workbook.write(fileOut);
workbook.close();
```

This code is working correctly for xlsx(`XSSFWorkbook`) using `XSSFStyle` format but changing template for when trying for xls(`HSSFWorkbook`) file.

Pleas find below template snippet before and after file generation.

- pre code template

[image: pre code template]

- post code template(Date format is coming as expected but template header color is changing from gray to green)

[image: post code template]